# Получение измененного значения из textarea(CKeditor)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Здравствуйте! Есть `textarea` с текстовым редактором `CKeditor` куда вставляется текст из БД:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor form-control field-input required alphanumeric"
               name="text" id="id<?=$row['id']?>"><?= $row['message']?></textarea>
```

И есть скрипт который получает значение из данной textarea:

```
$('.saveTemplate').on('click', function(){
        var saveTemplateId = this.id;
        var message = $('#id'+saveTemplateId).val();

        console.log(message);
              ....
```

Проблема заключается в том что, когда я меняю текст и нажимаю кнопку сохранить, я получаю изначальный текст, а не измененный, как будто его никто не трогал. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: [посмотрите тут мб...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906085/getting-the-textarea-value-of-a-ckeditor-textarea-with-javascript)

Comment: @Rostyslav Kuzmovych, спасибо! Но уже успел найти решение)

Comment: да незачто, я просто погуглил чуть-чуть :)

Answer (score 0):

Если кому понадобится)
`var message = CKEDITOR.instances['id'+saveTemplateId].getData();`